# Datetime index filtering and changing of values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

| Date | COL_1 | COL_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2017-04-21 | 0.0 | NaN |
| 2017-04-24 | 1.0 | 0.0 |
| 2017-04-25 | 0.0 | -1.0 |

Have the following table in datetime index.

What's the best way do I put in a conditional statement to filter where if COL_1 of the earliest index date is 0, COL_2 of the earliest index date, (Nan), is set to -1.

Need to keep it dynamic and filter without mentioning the specific dates.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

```
df.loc[(df.index == df.index.min()) & (df['COL_1'] == 0), 'COL_2'] = -1
print(df)

# Output
            COL_1  COL_2
2017-04-21    0.0   -1.0
2017-04-24    1.0    0.0
2017-04-25    0.0   -1.0
```